# Undefined or one?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Am I undefined, or am I one?
Do I tell what shouldn't be done?
Instead make a shift of two?
What is it that I do?

What is left over at the end?
Money is a close friend.
A veggie might stay near as well.
Who am I? Can you tell?

Comment: should this have a mathematics tag?  Seems like it could be answered with some math mumbo-jumbo

Comment: @Drt It could but it isn't restricted to that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> The % symbol

Am I undefined, or am I one?

> Looks like $\frac{0}{0}$, which many ask before they know if it is undefined or 1.

Do I tell what shouldn't be done?

> In several coding languages, % marks a comment

Instead make a shift of two?

> When converting to percent from decimal, shift the decimal point over two spaces

What is left over at the end?

> In most coding languages, % is modulus

Money is a close friend.

> Next to the $ symbol

A veggie might stay near as well.

> Next to the ^ (caret as in "carrot") symbol

Comment: You have the main idea. The second, third, and fourth clues as you wrote them have better interpretations. See if you can get those.

Comment: [The fourth clue?](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)

Comment: The second clue? (rot13: % pna qrabgr pbzzragf va GrK/YnGrK, CbfgFpevcg, naq ZNGYNO).

Comment: @AggieKidd Fixed now I hope!

Comment: @Dean Perfect. Well done.

Comment: @gnovice Thanks for the fourth clue hint, which led me to get the second clue on my own about the same time you typed your other comment :)

Answer (score 0):

My WAG would be

> a "tab"

Am I undefined, or am I one?

> Editors can arbitrarily define the length of a tab as X number of spaces; it can also define it as a distinct "character" in its own right (thinking of \t in regular expressions)

Do I tell what shouldn't be done?
Instead make a shift of two?

> I think this links with "taboo", if the 'o's were considered zeros.

What is it that I do?

> Don't know on this one.

What is left over at the end?

> Nor this.

Money is a close friend.

> One can have a "tab" with a retail establishment, a debt to be paid with money later.

A veggie might stay near as well.

> No idea on this.

Comment: Good guess, but no. The correct answer will work for all.